# Как работают Reactive Streams java?

Tags: java, rxjava, reactive

В целом разобрался с механизмом работы Reactive Streams, но не понимаю момент, когда  подписчик вызывает метод request(n) подписки(Subscription), чтобы запросить данные у издателя, как тот понимает, что нужно вызывать у Publisher onNext(data) ? В реализации Subscription есть ссылка на publisher? есть какая-то простая реализация этого механизма, чтобы можно было полностью разобраться?